# prove that every point in a 1d dynamical system *in ℤ* is either a fixed point, a periodic point, or an eventually periodic/fixed point

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I am studying a dynamical system $(ℤ,f)$ where $f(x)=\frac{x−x \bmod b}{b}+k \bmod b$ parametrized by $b,k \in \mathbb{Z},b\neq0$.

So it's either

- all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ are fixed points,
- all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ are periodic points of 2-cycles (so both 2-primecycles and fixed points),
- $x=0$ is a fixed point, all else converges to it (avoiding the term "attracting" coz later)
- $x=0,-1$ are fixed points, to which $[0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,-1]$ converges to (does these still count as basins of attraction?)
- $[0,b-1)$ is an absorbing interval composed of fixed points
- $[0,bk-1)$ is a positively invariant absorbing interval composed of generally, fixed points and periodic points

So here's the problem:
The phase space of the system is strictly $\mathbb{Z}$ so the concept of arbitrarily close values is irrelevant and I can't make use of epsilon-delta and lyapunov stability thingies to help me in my proofs. I even explicitly stated in my paper that we're not to talk about the stability of these points/cycles. Instead, when I have to prove that everything else converges to those points/intervals, I have to do it by induction.

And by induction, I mean doing induction up until the (quasi)period $b$ of the function, i.e. assume true for $n<b$, prove true for $n+1<b$, **then** doing induction by $b$ steps, i.e. assume true for $n$, prove true for $n+b$.

That's already twice the steps, then twice again if there's an interval (which is mostly the case), one for each bound of the interval. Now, imagine having to prove like 8 statements more or less like this. So I thought maybe we could prove beforehand, in one statement, that there will certainly be a fixed point, or an interval containing fixed points and periodic points, and *everything else* will converge to this point/interval.

So I would really appreciate some help on how I should approach this. I hope I do get responses this time, thank you.

**EDIT**:
Thinking about it, maybe we could approach it like this

For b>0 (points simply converge to point/interval)
Let $x^*\in\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose $f(x^*) = x^*$. If $f(x^*+1) \neq x^*+1$, then prove $f(x^*+n)< x^*+n$ for $n >= 1$. Also if $f(x^*-1) \neq x^*-1$, then prove $f(x^*-n)> x^*-n$ for $n >= 1$.

For b<0 (points jump to opposite sides of the number line), something like
Let $x^*\in\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose $f(x^*) = x^*$. If $|f(x^*+1)| \neq |x^*+1|$, then prove $|x^*-f(x^*+n)|< |x^*-(x^*+n)|$ for $n >= 1$. Also if $|f(x^*-1)| \neq |x^*-1|$, then prove $|x^*-f(x^*-n)|< |x^*-(x^*-n)|$ for $n >= 1$. If $|f(x^*+1)| \neq |x^*+1|$, it's either we've already landed on the fixed point, or $f(x)=-x$ so we just prove it converges for $f(x)=-x$.

I'll try it in a day, still open for insights and advice